# QGIS 'Save for All Layers' Signal

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is there a way in PyQGIS (QGIS Plugin) to know when the user does 'Save for All Layers'?

In the documentation for [QgisInterface](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/other/QgisInterface.html) I could not find this signal. But I really need to run a function after the user alters the data in the PostgreSQL tables (the layer source).

Comment: As of now, there is no signal from 'Save for All Layers' button. You can access that specific action from `QgisInterface` and connect to `QAction.triggered`, but that's not desirable because users could still cancel edits. What if you use `QgsVectorLayer.layerModified` signal instead?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Using `QgsVectorLayer.layerModified` is not helpful here. Since I want to get the signal after modification of all layers. The user might modify (specifically adding features) multiple layers; I want to execute a function after all the changes are effected on the sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `iface.actionSaveAllEdits().triggered` signal as below. `run` method runs after "Current edits" window is closed. It doesn't matter if the user chooses Yes or No.

```
def run():
    print("'Save for All Layers' was clicked")
    
iface.actionSaveAllEdits().triggered.connect(run)
```

But As Germán Carrillo mentioned, users could still cancel edits.

Comment: To downvoter: Please clarify why the answer deserves a downvote. Is it wrong or low quality (why?)? I'll understand, if just for **fun**.

Comment: Does this run after the data is saved or does it run first and then the data will be saved?

Comment: It  runs after data is saved. Therefore, you cannot avoid appearing "Current edits" window.